# Polynomials in nature

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, education, applications

What polynomials occur in "nature"? I am interested in polynomials of degree three and higher. I am aware of [Stefan Boltzmann Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) and [Chemical Equilibrium Examples](http://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/howtosolveit.html).

Edit:

There are some formulas under [beam deflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(engineering)) category.

I am particularly interested in full polynomials, as opposed to pure power laws. For example $y=at^2+v_0 t + y_0$ for a projectile uses a complete polynomial, while Boltzman law is just a power law.

Comment: Bruno Buchberger once told me something along the lines of "you can solve your problem if you can express it in polynomials." (Heavily paraphrased, highly innacurate, long-time-ago memory: please, nobody read very far into it :) ) That was right after a talk about automated proofs, so I imagine he was thinking along the lines of encoding proofs in polynomials. Much later, I saw a really cool automated proof of the concurrence of medians in a triangle using Buchberger's algorithm.

Comment: The volume of the sun is a degree-three polynomial of its radius...

Comment: The [ideal gas law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) can be thought of as an equality between a degree-three polynomial and a degree-two polynomial.

Comment: I've always been intrigued by the $r^4$ occuring in the Hagen-Poiseuille law.

Comment: 1st and 2nd orders very common but it is true that from 3 onwards it gets harder. I could generalise the answer above to   any volumes but it's a rather small family still.

Perhaps you could use them for approximations using Taylor series for example getting rid of $x^n$ onwards for some $n>3$ but it would only be an approximation of nature.

Kepler's third law uses a third degree relationship.

One more idea that come to my mind would be describing dynamical systems, could it be animals interacting or anything else really.

Comment: If you are looking for higher degree dependence moments of inertia give some examples - you get something varying like $mr^2$, but if the object is of uniform density $m$ varies as $r^2$ if it is scaled in two dimensions, and $r^3$ if scaled in three dimensions giving examples of $r^4$ and $r^5$ respectively (credit to WW Sawyer "Mathematician's Delight" if I remember rightly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Power Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) are probably what you are looking for and are very, very prevalent in physics, economics, linguistics and well, nature. They occur for phenomena that exhibit scale invariance. All forms of exponents occur. The [M-sigma law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-sigma_relation) has a power of 4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of science is inference of how [physical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity), [observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_variable), [latent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable) and derived quantities that constitute the natural universe are interrelated, to better predict how they will behave in the future and better understand the structure underlying them. This is an aim, regardless of whether the relationship is a universal law or a transient one, such as in stock market fluctuations. Polynomials are vital for describing these relationships, due to their simplicity and practicality and are a staple of [approximation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory). Higher degree polynomials often make better approximations *. Functions can represent how these quantities are interrelated but, unless otherwise stated, there is no reason these functions should be inherently well-behaved; they are not necessarily computable, differentiable, and so on. However, when we approximate a set of observed data-points by a polynomial, we are endowed with useful properties of the polynomial that make it tractable to find properties of the function such as roots and slope. In this sense, polynomials occur almost everywhere in nature, as a lens we can use to feasibly view the relationships between natural quantities.

This approach is justified by the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), which states that continuous functions can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial. The natural quantities we observe can typically be assumed to be continuous, at least to some degree, so this approach applies. If the true function can be represented by a convergent [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series), then higher degree polynomials will make better approximations **. For instance, consider the set of discrete observations of a time series, $\big((1,\sin1),\ (2,\sin2),\ (3,\sin3),\ldots,\ (n,\sin n)\big)$. Then, a good approximation of the time series would be $\sin t$, which could be used to interpolate and extrapolate for all real values. Since $\sin t$ can be given by a power series, in this case higher degree polynomials are indeed better approximations to the data set. However, in practice, it is typically better to approximate a function with just a *sufficiently* high degree polynomial. Using arbitrarily high degree polynomials takes longer to compute and does not always make a better approximation; [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) shows that raising the degree of interpolating polynomials can sometimes *increase* approximation error.

The advantage of using polynomials over other computable functions (e.g. exponential or trigonometric functions), is that polynomials can be easily evaluated with addition and multiplication alone, which can be easily encoded in [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation); they are continuous, smooth, entire, closed under multiplication and composition, and have asymptotes given simply by their highest power. They also have useful geometric and statistic [properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots) and have derivatives and integrals, easily obtained by the power rule, which not only describe their slope and quadrature but can sometimes aid [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) such as the Newton-Raphson method. These properties all fortify the ability of polynomials to describe the true function they represent.

---

* This is not always the case. See: [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

** See also: [*Approximating functions by Taylor Polynomials.*](http://www.math.smith.edu/~rhaas/m114-00/chp4taylor.pdf).